# Choose lens for Olympus OM-1n

Tags: lens, lens-adapter, olympus, olympus-om1

I just got an Olympus OM-1N since I decided to play with analog photography. It came with the regular 50mm f/1.8 lens which is quite fine for many occasions, however I realized that I need a wide-angle lens. The problem I face with the original Zuiko glass is that I cannot find a lens which is in good condition and relatively cheap. Many of them are being sold for ridiculous prices (over 300 euros/dollars) and with notes like: "a little bit of dust inside", which might not be technically a problem, but it bugs me.

What are my alternatives? I've read about adaptors, etc. but I assume there are downsides to this approach (the adaptor changes the physical distance between lens' elements and the shutter). At this point I don't care having the original Olympus lens, but rather a good, reliable lens that performs well.

Comment: If 300 euros/dollars is a ridiculous price, can you suggest what your budget is? "Shopping" questions are not accepted here, but I'm thinking that maybe you just need some general advice rather than a specific purchase recommendation.

Comment: Just dropping a couple of excellent OM resources here... [mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/olympusom1n2/shared/zuiko/index.htm](http://mir.com.my/rb/photography/hardwares/classics/olympusom1n2/shared/zuiko/index.htm) [olympus.dementix.org/eSIF/om-sif/lensgroup.htm](http://olympus.dementix.org/eSIF/om-sif/lensgroup.htm)

Comment: @osullic Please correct me if I'm wrong here (honestly I'm reading and learning, still), but if one of the "modern" lenses (we're talking about similar specs here) costs around 7-8 hundred euros/dollars, then paying 300-350 for a 40-year old lens with dust, or maybe some haze, sounds a bit too much. I don't have a budget, since I knew from the beginning that it's an expensive hobby, but I am trying to put some common sense in my purchases. I have the feeling that the reason for these prices might be collectors as well.

Comment: With age & reputation comes outlay. Try buying a brand new Fender Stratocaster… then have a look at prices for a 1956 model in good condition. Same applies to cars, & many other things initially mass-produced.

Comment: @Tetsujin The Strat example really hit me. Apparently that's the case, that's why I am asking whether there are any alternatives.

Comment: Sigma made some very nice 24mm lenses. You should be able to find one with an OM mount. If you are only going to do architectural and landscape work with it, you won't need to bother with auto-focus.

Comment: @Mick The OM system is a manual focus system. There are no autofocus options, full-stop.

Comment: Guys thank you all for your time and suggestions. I think there was a lot of discussion regarding what I mentioned about the cost. Again, that was not a shopping question, but rather a question about alternative solutions to the original OM lenses - and whether we like or not, cost IS a contributing factor. If you think the question should be edited please do so, or suggest edits. On the other hand, if you think you are answering the question please write it as an answer below so I can accept it.

Comment: Looking at KEH Photo yields plenty of options cheaper than $300. https://www.keh.com/shop/lenses/slr/olympus-manual-focus--prime-fixed-focal-length--wide-angle.html?price=0-200&product_list_order=price_asc